# eigen value problem of the following matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & 3 & -2 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 3 \\ -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & -3 & 1 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

**4.9** Pick out the smallest disc in the complex plane containing all the eigenvalues of $A$ from amongst the following:

1. $|z-1| \leq 7$;
2. $|z-1| \leq 6$;
3. $|z-1| \leq 4$.

How to solve the problem 4.9?

Comment: Please, instead of inserting an image, use TeX.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial of the matrix $$A:=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & 3 & -2 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 3 \\ -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & -3 & 1 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$ is $$\det(A-x I)=x^4-4x^3+21x^2-48x+46.$$

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4-4%2ax%5E3%2b21%2ax%5E2-48%2ax%2b46) approximates its roots as $$0.4956 \pm 3.8331i$$ and $$1.5044 \pm 0.9033i.$$  These are approximately the eigenvalues of the matrix.

Now it's a matter of finding which is the smallest disc containing these four complex numbers.